# Expected value of larger cut (basic probability)

Tags: probability, expected-value

I looked around a few questions on the site and examples from my textbooks and couldn't really understand how the expected value of something is calculated.
I'm a student of computer science and for some reason they decided to teach us tons of probability subjects in less than a week cause we need it to analyze running time of code.

So i would like a (simple words, im slow) explanation of the idea if Expected value and help regarding this specific question:

Let us have a Chocolate bar of the size n (1 to n).
Let us choose some index k and split the bar at that index. We give one part to our friend and leave the other to ourselves. We LOVE chocolate so we always take the bigger part of the bar for ourselves.
What is the Expected size of the piece we will get? (You may approximate when confronted with non integers).

(NOTES): We learned of basic probabilty and ONLY the definition of probability space. We learned of Expected value generally, and specifically about its linearity and about the face that when the random indicator variables X, Y are independent this occurs: E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)

[EDIT:edit: fixed picture with my try to solve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bte3S.jpg)

Comment: I read "of size n(1-n)" and do not really understand what you mean by that. Is $n$ some natural number? If so then the size can only be $0$ (preassuming that the size is not negative).

Comment: Sorry guys, i fixed the question. its (1 to n), not a minus!

Comment: And as far as i understand (sorry, i'm really new to probability) k is uniformaly distributed - the chance of choosing the index k is 1/n

Comment: Do you mean that the division $0:n$ is also possible?

Comment: Yes. Technically this should be (to my understanding) 3n/4

Comment: What does the symbol "$x_n$" in your picture mean? Why are the summands independent of the summation index "$i$"?

Comment: @user my bad, it should be Xi and represent the random variable that gives 0 if i != k and 1 otherwise. i will fix the equation and reupload

Comment: $E(x)=\sum_i x_i p_i$. What you have written is still rubbish. Hint: $x_i=\text{max}(i,n-i)$, and not something else you have ascribed to it.

Answer (score 1):

I preassume that the index $k$ must be an element of $\{1,2,\dots, n-1\}$.

There are so-called events that can occur and let $E_k$ denote the event that the bar is split at $k$. In that case the size of the piece we get is $\max(k,n-k)$.

Further the events $E_1,E_2,\dots, E_{n-1}$ are firstly mutually exclusive which means that at most one of the events will occur. Secondly they are covering which means that at leas one of the events will occur. Taking this together we just get the statement that exactly one of the events will occur.

Then consequently if $p_k$ denotes the probability that event $E_k$ will occur we have:$$p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_{n-1}=1\tag1$$

The expectation of the length of the piece we get takes the shape:$$p_1\max(1,n-1)+p_2\max(2,n-2)+\cdots+p_{n-1}\max(n-1,1)\tag2$$

It might be that you had in mind already that the mentioned events have equal probability to occur. If so then on base of $(1)$ we find that $p_k=\frac1{n-1}$ for every $k$ and $(2)$ simplifies to:$$\frac1{n-1}\left(\max(1,n-1)+\max(2,n-2)+\cdots+\max(n-1,1)\right)\tag3$$

(Good exercise to find the outcome as an expression in $n$ yourself)

It can be shown that - if you share a lot of such pieces of chocolate - then the average of the length of the piece we get will come very close to this expression. And the expression is unique in having that property. This to give you an idea of the importance/background of the concept "expectation".

Comment: Thanks for giving me so much of your time!
I understand the concept a bit better now (though i think you misunderstood that 0:n is possible as well)
But now i still don't understand the issue of how all of this logic is connected to the formalities.
Such as E[x] = x*p(x)
and creating random indicators etc..

Comment: I guess the last term should be $p_{n-1}\text{max}(n-1,1)$ (if the division $0:n$ is not possible).

Comment: @user Yes, of course. Thanks for attending. Repaired.

Comment: Not sure if the site informs of an edit, so i add this comment to make sure you notice

Comment: @ash: To be sure that your message is noticed use  "@username" in the body.

Comment: You are welcome. If preassumed that at least some chocolate would be given away so excluded $k=0$ and $k=n$. Good luck further with your study on probabilities. The fact there is some improvement of your understandings is enough for me already. You must dive into it and learn how to swim.

Comment: @drhab I added a picture to the original post and a comment here to make my gaps in understanding clearer

Answer (score 0):

The expected value is simply the average size of the piece we will get over a large number of trials. In this case

If $k<=\frac{n}{2}$ then you get the other piece ((n-k) of the chocolate)

If $k>=\frac{n}{2}$ then you get that piece (k of the chocolate)

We are assuming k is evenly distributed, so both the possibilities are equally likely. Thus, the average cut will be made halfway in the middle of the interval.

We must then add up the overall expected value as follows:

E(k) = 0.5 * (average value of k in the first interval) + 0.5 * (1-average value of k in the second interval)

(The 0.5 is because both are equally likely)

Since the average values of k are $\frac{n}{4}$ and $\frac{3n}{4}$ in the two intervals, the resulting average (expected) size of chocolate is $\frac{3n}{4}$

Comment: Can you explain in more technical terms how you got to that conclusion? I think i generally understand the logic behind the answer and i can't grasp my head around how the technicalities work and that would help me in the future.

Comment: @ash, I have tried to make my answer more formal.

Comment: I saw your calculations, but I feel it is easier if you get rid of the max function, as there are clearly two possibilities

Comment: So, split that sum into two separate parts

Comment: I don't completely understand how you get the result you do. I understand the logic but not the math behind it. re-uploaded a more detailed image of my attempt.